# WSL: Couldn't rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlesim-node, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the beginner rosnode tutorial
http://[wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes).

The environment is Windows 10 / WSL. When I enter command `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node` after running "roscore", I get the following error:

```
wn-003% rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
zsh: abort (core dumped)  rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

Are there any solutions to this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315056/wsl:-couldn%27t-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/) by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The environment is Windows 10 / WSL. [..] `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display`. Are there any solutions to this?

Do you have an X server running and have you setup everything to use that X server?

Please note that ROS on Ubuntu on WSL on Windows 10 is *not* a supported configuration, so you're bound to run into issues.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on 2019-02-08**:
I've downloaded X server and I succeeded `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node` 
Thank you!

**Comment by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on 2019-02-08**:
Oh no! When I restart PC and do `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node` .I get the same error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-08**:
Have you restarted the X server? The X servers for Windows I know are not services, nor part of "the system", but regular programs. So you'll have to start them manually.

**Comment by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on 2019-02-08**:
Yes, I restarted the X server. But failed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-08**:
Is the `DISPLAY` variable also set?

**Comment by [shmpwk](https://answers.ros.org/users/39767/shmpwk/) on 2019-02-08**:
yes in .bashrc file, there is

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-08**:
Well, as I wrote in my answer, this is not a supported configuration. Although it can work -- as I've seen many people set things up this way, and I've done it myself -- there is no guarantee.